# python - JAR works in terminal but not from python

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, terminal, subprocess

I working on a python 3 script for doing some bench (school purpose). So I need to invoke my JAR.
I use subprocess.check_output for that.

```
 java_out = subprocess.check_output("java -jar my_jar.jar -p input_file", shell=True)
```

In terminal it works fine, I get the expected output and exit code is 0.
But in python, I get this :

```
Syntax error. (One of my java exception, but it might not happen in this case)
Traceback (most recent call last):


 File "C:/Users/Jeremy/PycharmProjects/bench_bf/bench_script.py", line 41, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Jeremy/PycharmProjects/bench_bf/bench_script.py", line 32, in main
    result_list.append(bench(bf_file, stats_file))
  File "C:/Users/Jeremy/PycharmProjects/bench_bf/bench_script.py", line 10, in bench
    java_out = subprocess.check_output("java -jar my_jar.jar -p input_file", shell=True)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 620, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'java -jar my_jar.jar -p input_file' returned non-zero exit status 5

Process finished with exit code 1
```

That does not make any sense to me. Can anyone help me ? Thanks !
The full code is following (I've also tried with absolute path) :)

```
import subprocess
import os
import re

FILE_NAME = "input_file"
JAR_NAME = "my_jar.jar"
TEST_ITER = 5

def bench(bf_file, stats_file):
    java_out = subprocess.check_output("java -jar "+ JAR_NAME + " -p " + FILE_NAME, shell=True)
    print(java_out)
    m = re.search(".*EXEC_TIME : (\d*) ms.*EXEC_MOVE : (\d*)", java_out)
    return [m.group(0), m.group(1)]

def init_stats(f):
    f.write("Iterations; Exec time; exec move")

def write_file(f):
    f.write("+++")

def main():

    bf_file = open(FILE_NAME, "w", encoding="utf-8")
    stats_file = open("bench-result.csv", "w")

    write_file(bf_file)
    init_stats(stats_file);

    result_list = []
    for i in range(0,TEST_ITER):
        result_list.append(bench(bf_file, stats_file))
    average_time = 0;
    for res in result_list:
        average_time += res[0]
    average_time /= TEST_ITER;
    stats_file.write(average_time + ";" + result_list[0][1])



main()
```

EDIT: I also tried java_out = subprocess.check_output(["java", "-jar", "my_jar.jar", "-p", "input_file"], shell=True), it changes nothing.

EDIT 2: Same result using absolute path or os.system

*** SOLUTION ***
Since I open the file in write mode, my JAR can't open it, and consider it's empty... Thanks my mate DjNikita :)

Comment: did you try with full paths for `java` and `my_jar.jar` ? I run your code (and I don't have `my_jar.jar`) and I get the same error.

Comment: Yes I've tried this possibilities, but thanks for the help anyway !

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: Invalid syntax, he doesn't recognize my '+' (and he should). But when I add a print in my java code, the print is like "skipped"

Comment: With absolute paths is it the same error?

Comment: can you print your current directory? it may not be the one you're thinking it is.

Comment: run this `os.system("java -jar my_jar.jar -p input_file")` and you'll get the error message, not just the return code (also would work with `subprocess.Popen`)

Comment: The directory is the good one (and absolute path change nothing). With os.system it's the same results. The exception makes no sense because the syntax in the file is good. So I shouldn't have any :/ But thanks for the help anyway !

Comment: Same result but you should get some output in the python console. What is this output ?

Comment: I get exactly the same output (only stderr):
`Syntax error : ?`

Answer (score -1):

My first thought would be that there is something in your environment that is not transferring to the subprocess. Try this and see if it outputs anything that looks relevant

```
import os
for key in os.environ:
    if any(token in key.lower() for token in ['java', 'jre', 'jdk']):
        print(key, os.environ[key])
```

I've had another thought too. Some programs expect their input to be a tty (ie. interactive terminal) and get angry when they're fed in a pipe. Is there anything in your Java program that might cause it to expect a certain type of input stream?

Comment: Thank you for your help ! My JAVA_HOME is good, I got the good jdk version and stuff

Comment: I added another possible problem there could be.

Comment: My java just expect a file name and read it with a BufferedReader. So I guess it's ok

Answer (score -1):

Try specifying the absolute path of the jar file, as it might be that your sub-process isn't running the directory you think it is.

Try running 'dir' and seeing where it returns, for instance.  Maybe check that 'java --V' (the version flag? not in a position to check at the moment) returns something indicating that Java ran, rather than an error.  Basically, try and get a simple thing running via Python, then extend it.

Comment: I've tried dir, and it's the good directory, even with absolute path it won't work....

Comment: Hmm, I really wish people who down vote would comment as to what they're objecting to.  I hope it wasn't the OP, as there are two things to try, and it's not clear if the validation of the java invocation has been attempted...

Comment: I didn't down vote if it's what you were meaning ;) Every comment is helpful, even (more) if it's not successful, because it shows other way of thinking

Comment: I hoped so! As I said, I'd try and check that java is running, maybe just the basic command with no jar file, then if ok, a helloworld.jar, etc.  If you can get to a stage where something works, it's easier to narrow down the bit that's going wrong than at present.